# in vue-cli 3.0 how to generate complete webpack.config.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

In vue-cli-3.0， how to generate complete webpack.config.js.
i have tried as the tutor but i failed with an error 
my trial code is just as below.

```
import a from "@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js"
console.log(a)
```

and the error is as below,i don't know why it does not work.

"Invalid left-hand side in assignment
at Object../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js"

is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the webpack configuration is composed dynamically by the vue cli and plugins.

If you need to tweak the config you can do so in the `vue.config.js` as described [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html)

You can also use the `vue inspect` to see the resolved configuration.

> Note the output is not a valid webpack config file, it's a serialized format only meant for inspection.

Comment: Thank you very much,i've tried as you said and it worked.

Comment: But I still have a question.
Do you know what does this mean
[link](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config)

Comment: And ,what does 
'Note the output is not a valid webpack config file, it's a serialized format only meant for inspection.'
mean ,then which part may be incorrect?

Comment: The output of "vue inspect" allows you to see what the final configuration options are, that way you can test if the vue.config.js made the changes you wnated. But you can't use it as a webpack.config.js in another project.

Comment: So,if i want to generate a webpack.config.js which can be used in another project, what should i do?

Comment: Use the older v2 vue-cli, that one generates a (complicated) webpack.config.js split over multiple files. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack or write your own config